# Returning a selection of a list of objects from a view

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Ok, so I a writing a view to receive the following model:

```
public class OrderCourseViewModel
{
    public Department Department { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LocalizedCourse> Courses { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Profile> People { get; set; }

    public int SelectedCourseId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedPeopleList { get; set; } 

}
```

The idea is that the user is presented with a wizard-view. First page is list of courses where they can select one course. Then click Next and they are presented with a list of people and can make a selection. Then click next again to be presented with an overview of what they selected.

The SelectedCourseId was simple using javascript to set a hidden value, but I am having trouble getting the id's of the people selected into the list SelectedPeopleList.

To make it worse Im not using checkboxes or anything like that, I am making a list of divs that you can toggle on/off.

Here is the people-part of the Select view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="wiz2">
        @foreach (var person in Model.People)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_SelectCoursePerson", person)
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the small _SelectCoursePerson view

```
@model Kursbyen.Profile
<div class="col-sm-10 img-rounded course" style="border: solid 1px #000000; padding:15px; margin:10px" onclick="javascript: toggleSelected(this, @Model.Id);">
<div class="col-sm-4"><profile picture></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="padding-right:5px">@Model.LastName, @Model.FirstName</div>
</div>
```

As you probably can tell I am somewhat inexperienced in asp, but is my approach completely stupid? Should I do it differently? Please help out if you can.

If possible I would of course also like to maintain state so that I can go back and still have the same people toggled on even after a refresh.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does toggleSelected do? What's happening on form submit?

To get the selected People back up to the server on the next request, you'll need to somehow create form data from them. You can do that by appending INPUT elements to the DOM, or by building form data in javascript that runs when the form is submitted.

Comment: atm all toggleSelected does is toggle a class to show that the current person is selected or not. I guess the problem is that I am not sure how to write the INPUT elements so that the model binding will work as intended.

Comment: You might check out http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ for details on how model binding to IEnumerables works. You'll still have to deal with getting those items added to the DOM as INPUT elements.

Comment: esmoore: That perfectly explained it, thank you.
Could you please post that as a reply I can set it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check out haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx for details on how model binding to IEnumerables works. You'll still have to deal with getting those items added to the DOM as INPUT elements.